# $unset on multiple fields in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a collection in mongoDB like given below -

```
{
name : "Abhishek",
Roll_no : null,
hobby : stackoverflow
},
{
name : null,
Roll_no : 1,
hobby : null
}
```

Now I want to delete the fields in my Documents where the field values are null. I know that I can do it using the `$unset` in following way -

```
db.collection.updateMany({name: null}, { $unset : { name : 1 }});
```

And we could do it in the same way for hobby and name field.

But I was wondering if I can do the same **deletion operation using just one query**? I was wondering if maybe I could use `$or` or something else to achieve the same effect but in a single command.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your DB version ?

Comment: 4.0.15 but consider I can update it to the latest version.

Comment: Ok if you can upgrade to `4.2` you'll have better options to deal with it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On MongoDB version >= `3.2` :**

You can take advantage of `.bulkWrite()` :

```
let bulkArr = [
  {
    updateMany: {
      filter: { name: null },
      update: { $unset: { name: 1 } }
    }
  },
  {
    updateMany: {
      filter: { Roll_no: null },
      update: { $unset: { Roll_no: 1 } }
    }
  },
  {
    updateMany: {
      filter: { hobby: null },
      update: { $unset: { hobby: 1 } }
    }
  },
];

/** All filter conditions will be executed on all docs
 *  but respective update operation will only be executed if respective filter matches (kind of individual ops) */
db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkArr);
```

**Ref :** [bulkwrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html#db-collection-bulkwrite)

**On MongoDB version >= `4.2` :**

Since you wanted to delete multiple fields(where field names can't be listed down or unknown) having `null` value, try below query :

```
db.collection.update(
  {}, // Try to use a filter if possible
  [
    /** 
     * using project as first stage in aggregation-pipeline
     * Iterate on keys/fields of document & remove fields where their value is 'null'
     */
    {
      $project: {
        doc: {
          $arrayToObject: { $filter: { input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }, cond: { $ne: ["$$this.v", null] } } }
        }
      }
    },
    /** Replace 'doc' object as root of document */
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" }
    }
  ],
  { multi: true }
);
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ylutA1OYBhw)

**Ref :** [update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) , [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

**Note :**

I believe this would be one time operation & in future you can use `Joi` npm package or mongoose schema validators to restrict writing `null`'s as field values. If you can list down your field names as if not too many plus dataset size is way too high then try to use aggregation with `$$REMOVE` as suggested by '@thammada'.

As of now, aggregation-pipeline in `.updateMany()` is not supported by many clients even few mongo shell versions - back then my ticket to them got resolved by using `.update()`, if it doesn't work then try to use `update + { multi : true }`.

Comment: I'm curious, does aggregation pipeline in `.updateMany()` also subject to memory limits of regular aggregation pipeline, is there a similar way to allow disk usage?

Comment: @thammada : not sure about that, but in general I believe it may not be an issue with the stages being used in `.update()`'s cause most of the times you run of out memory when you try to accumulate docs like when using `$group` or `$sort` for computation.

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB v4.2, you can do [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), along with the [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.REMOVE) system variable

```js
db.collection.updateMany({ 
  $or: [{
    name: null
  }, {
    Roll_no: null
  }, {
    hobby: null
  }]
}, [{
  $set: {
    name: { $ifNull: ["$name", "$$REMOVE"] }
    Roll_no: { $ifNull: ["$Roll_no", "$$REMOVE"] },
    hobby: { $ifNull: ["$hobby", "$$REMOVE"] }
  }
}]
```