# Mongo aggregate is not updating the actual document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

> As can be seen from the below example when I do aggregation it spits
>   out the required result but the actual result is not getting replaces.
>   Could some tell me how to persist aggregate o/p?

```
> db.demo95.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eed924ae3fc5c755e1198a2"), "Id" : "5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a" }
> db.demo95.aggregate([ { "$addFields": { "Id" : { "$toObjectId": "$Id" } }} ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eed924ae3fc5c755e1198a2"), "Id" : ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a") }
> db.demo95.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eed924ae3fc5c755e1198a2"), "Id" : "5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a" }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregate is supposed to *read* the data from a collection. You can *write* the output to *another* collection by using a [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) or [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) stage.

Only from v4.4 (not generally available yet as of June 20th, 2020), you can use a [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) stage to output to the [same collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-behavior-same-collection).

However, starting from version 4.2, you can use ["updates with aggregation pipeline"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). The syntax for the pipeline is the same, but you can use only selected stages.

Your query can be translated to:

```
db.demo95.updateMany({}, [ { "$addFields": { "Id" : { "$toObjectId": "$Id" } }} ])
```

Refer to [updateMany with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline) for more information.

If you have an issue with `updateMany`, you can refer to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203486) by [@whoami](https://stackoverflow.com/u/7237613) on a different question:

> As of now, aggregation-pipeline in `.updateMany()` is not supported by
>   many clients even few mongo shell versions - back then my ticket to
>   them got resolved by using `.update()`, if it doesn't work then try to
>   use `update + { multi : true }`.